# getnameinfo returning numeric name with "%<interface>"

Tags: linux, network-programming, ip, ipv6

I'm using `getnameinfo` as follows:

```
ifaddrs *ifaddr = NULL, *ifa = NULL;
int rc, family, insize;

rc = getifaddrs(&ifaddr);
...

for (ifa = ifaddr; ifa != NULL; ifa = ifa->ifa_next) {
    family = ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family
    insize = (family == AF_INET) ?
            (int)sizeof(struct sockaddr_in) :
            (int)sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6);

    char host[HOST_NAME_MAX];
    rc = getnameinfo(ifa->ifa_addr, insize,
            host, sizeof(host), NULL, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST);
}
...
```

When the function returns with an IPv6 address, it include the interface appended to the numeric IP address:

```
fe80::62a4:4cff:fe05:dc1b%eth0
```

What's the purpose of appending the interface to the numerical IP address?

Is there a flag available that controls the appending of the interface to the IP address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fe80::*` addresses are [link-local](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) in scope, which means the address is only valid for that particular network, the same address may reference a difference host on a different network.  It is thus meaningless to specify a link-local address without specifying which network adapter.  Also, DNS becomes rather meaningless outside of link-local scope such as provided by [ZeroConf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) / multicast-DNS.

Unix hosts tend to specify the adapter by name, Windows hosts will specify the adapter by index.  Note that Windows maintains separate interface indexes for IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: "It is thus meaningless to specify a link-local address without specifying which network adapter" - how in the hell did they manage to run out of IPv6 addresses given the damn things are 16 bytes? Its not like they don't have room for 4 or 6 bits for an index in the lower 8 octets.... What's next? [IPv9](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1606) so they can really provide all the required addresses?

Comment: @noloader: IPv6 addresses didn't run out, and link-local addresses are quite useful for autoconfiguration, routing protocols and ZeroConf/Bonjour style services. And remember that IPv6 has multiple addresses per interface, so next to your link-local address you usually have a few global unicast addresses.